# How do I see inherited width and keep data inside pre tag

Tags: html, css

I am using pre tags to display some php and javascript code of a project but the code shows outside the border of the containing element. In the console I am trying to find where the element is getting its width from or what the container div width is. In the css file the parent wrapper div has a width of 100% but some of the containing elements show a much more narrower width but I don't see it in the console when inspecting the element. The pre spills over outside the the border as can be seen here: https://www.z1labs.com/

CSS

```
body {
    font:1.1em 'Source Sans Pro';
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-weight:400;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}

.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.upload-console {
    background:#fefefe;
    border:2px solid #eee;
    padding:20px;
}

.upload-console-header {
    padding:0 0 20px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.upload-console-drop {
    height:200px;
    border:2px dashed #ccc;
    line-height:200px;
    color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.upload-console-drop.drop {
    border-color:#222;
    color:#222;
}

.upload-console-body {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.bar {
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.bar-fill {
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    background:cornflowerblue;
    width:0;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.8s ease;
    transition:width 0.8s ease;
}

.bar-fill-text {
    color:#fff;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.upload-console-upload {
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.upload-console-upload span {
    float:right;
}

pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I do I see where an element is getting its width and how do I keep the code inside the pre tag? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

add `white-space: pre-wrap;` on `pre` tag & also proper `formatting` your code

```
pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow-x: scroll;` on `pre` tag

```
pre {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Give the `overflow: auto` for your `pre` tag so that content will set inside the border.

```
pre {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```